# Teaspoon showing some weird error on CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci, teaspoon

I am using teaspoon for some javascript testing (written in CoffeeScript) on my development machine everything works great:

```
→ bundle exec rake teaspoon
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:58786/teaspoon/default
................

Finished in 0.02500 seconds
16 examples, 0 failures
```

But on the CircleCI it ends with following error.

```
$ bundle exec rake teaspoon --trace
** Invoke teaspoon (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute teaspoon
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:60894/teaspoon/default
Failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:60894/teaspoon/default?reporter=Console bundle exec rake teaspoon --trace returned exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at CircleCI. It's a little difficult to figure out what's going on here just from the info above. Can you please ping us at sayhi@circleci.com and we can get things sorted out?

Comment: We solved it via support. Error was caused by `config.force_ssl=true` option for test environment in our rails app. After setting `config.force_ssl=false` for teaspoon tests everything works great. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem and I haven't managed to solve it with neither force_ssl option set to false, neither with solution proposed below. I went to track down when this problem happened and if something that I've commit affected it, but it just came out of nowhere.
Here is the latest failed build, where you can see the error -> https://circleci.com/gh/moonleerecords/moonlee-website/158 (check the tab "bundle exec rake teaspoon").

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had to add the following to `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( teaspoon-jasmine.js jasmine/1.3.1.js teaspoon-teaspoon.js teaspoon.css )
```

..and then restart the server.

This was because I am using jasmine and it needs to be pre-compiled in order to work.